# Why my simple python web crawler runs very slowly?

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape about 34,000 pages. I calculated the time to find that it takes more than 5 seconds on average to request each page. Since I am directly scraping data from APIs, I only used the requests package. Is there any way that I could speed up my crawler? Or if it is not possible, how can I deploy the crawler to a server?

Here's some of my code:

```
# Using python selenium to scrape sellers on shopee.co.id
# Crawl one seller -> Crawl all sellers in the list
# Sample URL: https://shopee.co.id/shop/38281755/search
# Sample API: https://shopee.co.id/api/v2/shop/get?shopid=38281755
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
import time

PATH_1 = '/Users/lixiangyi/FirstIntern/temp/seller_list.csv'
shop_list = pd.read_csv(PATH_1)
shop_ids = shop_list['shop'].tolist()
# print(seller_list)

# Downloading all APIs of shopee sellers:
api_links = []  # APIs of shops
item_links = []  # Links to click into
for shop_id in shop_ids:
    api_links.append('https://shopee.co.id/api/v2/shop/get?shopid=' + str(shop_id))
    item_links.append(
        f'https://shopee.co.id/api/v2/search_items/?by=pop&limit=10&match_id={shop_id}&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=shop&version=2'
    )
# print(api_links)


shop_names = []
shopid_list = []
founded_time = []
descriptions = []
i = 1

for api_link in api_links[0:100]:
    start_time = time.time()
    shop_info = requests.get(api_link)
    shopid_list.append(shop_info.text)
    print(i)
    i += 1
    end_time = time.time()
    print(end_time - start_time)
```

Comment: It could be that the API is rate-limited, in which case there is probably nothing you can do (except pay them, if they offer a higher-quality paid service). Although it may help to find a way to get the information you need with fewer API calls.

Comment: It is possible to improve your scrape speed. However, since you are targetting one site, increasing your speed is liable to get your IP address blocked, and deservedly so. Some scrape speeds are so good that you are effectively performing a denial of service attack on the target, to the detriment of the owner and other users.

Answer (score 2):

You should be trying to retrieve multiple URLs in parallel using either threading or the `aiohttp` package. Using threading:

**Update**

Since all your requests are going against the same website, it will be more efficient to use a [`requests.Session`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session) object for making your retrievals. However, regardless of how you go about retrieving these URLs, issuing too many requests from the same IP address to the same website in a short period of time could be interpreted as a Denial of Service attack.

```py
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial
import time

api_links = [] # this will have been filled in
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}

shopid_list = []

def retrieve_url(session, url):
    shop_info = session.get(url)
    return shop_info.text


NUM_THREADS = 75 # experiment with this value
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_THREADS) as executor:
    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.headers = headers
        # session will be the first argument to retrieve_url:
        worker = partial(retrieve_url, session)
        start_time = time.time()
        for result in executor.map(worker, api_links):
            shopid_list.append(result)
        end_time = time.time()
        print(end_time - start_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

use python `urllib` library

```
import urllib.request 
request_url = urllib.request.urlopen(some-url) 
print(request_url.read())
```

Comment: I find that `requests` runs just as fast if not faster and is recommended by Python's own documentation.